# Spring Boot with Thymeleaf handling DateTime field

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, datetime-format

I am using Spring Boot v2.0.3 with Thymeleaf. I have a problem with persisting or editing a date field declared as follow:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss")
@Column(name = "date_agenda", nullable = false)
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@NotNull(message = "la date doit être renseignée")
@XmlElement
Date dateAgenda;
```

here is my controller:

```
// Save
@RequestMapping(value = "/agendaEdit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String agendaEdit(@Valid Agenda agenda, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "/agenda/agendaEdit";
    } else {
        agendaService.saveAgenda(agenda);
        model.addAttribute("agenda", agendaService.getAllAgenda());
        return "/agenda/agendaList";
    }
}
```

and my template:

```
<div class="form-group"
     th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('agenda.dateAgenda')} ? 'has-error'">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="content">Date</label>
        <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="content" th:field="*{agenda.dateAgenda}"/>
        <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('agenda.dateAgenda')}"
           th:errors="*{agenda.dateAgenda}" class="help-block">Name Error</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I got the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is in the `@DateTimeFormat`'s pattern: with `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss"` you are parsing the seconds, which are not part of the *datetime-local* input.

Use `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm"` instead and it will work as expected.